# Critical value example where partial derivative does not exist

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Each of the following functions has a critical value where the partial derivatives do not exist.

1. $f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{1/3}$
2. $f(x,y)=1-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$
3. $f(x,y)=3-[(x-1)(y-2)]^{2/3}$

Does anyone have any cuter examples?

Comment: Is there something in particular you're looking for?  There are a limitless number of ways to create a cusp in a surface (note that all of these functions involve a positive exponent between 0 and 1).

Comment: @RecklessReckoner How about an example where you get two critical values, one where both partial derivatives equal zero and one where at least one of the partial derivatives is undefined?

Comment: Add together a function with a cusp and a function with a conventional critical point of the "opposite sign", say,  $ \ z \ = \ (x^2+y^2)^{1/3} \ - \ 0.1( \ [x-1]^2 \ + \ [y-2]^2 \ ) \ $ , just as one possibility. Now you have a local minimum "cusp" at the origin and a local maximum "hill" at $ \ (1, \ 2 ) \ $ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Nice job. Thanks for the help. It will be very useful teaching class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider $f(x,y) = |x|$, which has infinitely many critical points along the line $x=0$, where its partial derivative does not exist.